# Failed to sign request when using AWS SDK for GO V2 - Visual Studio - Lambda Sample

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code, aws-lambda

I am a newbie trying to learn AWS and Visual StudioCode(newbie as well).
I installed the SDK, created AWS account and authenticated the SDK on Visual Studio Code.
While I try to run a sample code found on Amazon site, I encounter error, looks like authentication issue to me.
package main

```
import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/lambda"
)

func main() {
    sdkConfig, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO(), config.WithRegion("us-east-1"))

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Couldn't load default configuration. Have you set up your AWS account?")
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    lambdaClient := lambda.NewFromConfig(sdkConfig)

    maxItems := 10
    fmt.Printf("Let's list up to %v functions for your account.\n", maxItems)
    result, err := lambdaClient.ListFunctions(context.TODO(), &lambda.ListFunctionsInput{
        MaxItems: aws.Int32(int32(maxItems)),
    })
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Couldn't list functions for your account. Here's why: %v\n", err)
        return
    }
    if len(result.Functions) == 0 {
        fmt.Println("You don't have any functions!")
    } else {
        for _, function := range result.Functions {
            fmt.Printf("\t%v\n", *function.FunctionName)
        }
    }
}
```

I get the below error,

```
Couldn't list functions for your account. Here's why: operation error Lambda: ListFunctions, exceeded maximum number of attempts, 3, failed to sign request: failed to retrieve credentials: failed to refresh cached credentials, no EC2 IMDS role found, operation error ec2imds: GetMetadata, exceeded maximum number of attempts, 3, request send failed, Get "http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/": dial tcp 169.254.169.254:80: connect: host is down
```

When I use the private key -i on ssh connect to the server it connects.
In AWS SDK I can see it is connect too.
[VS Code AWS SDK Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95nXb.png)

I checked a few YouTube videos and most of the say about ID and Passcode, however as I understand it is the approach for IAM and not IAM Identity Center.